# How do I spawn a chest filled with command blocks containing a TP command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to `/setblock` a chest filled with command blocks with this command pre-entered in all of them:

> "/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000".

All I have tried was Google, and I couldn't find it anywhere. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BlockEntityTag` tag for item data will hold the potential NBT data for the tile entity variant of that item. For example, the following creates a chest with a command block in Slot 0 that has the command requested:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}}]}
```

For every slot, it's just a matter of copying/pasting the item compound while changing `Slot` (and changing `Count` as desired):

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:1,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:2,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:3,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:4,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:5,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:6,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:7,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:8,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:9,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:10,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:11,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:12,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:13,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:14,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:15,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:16,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:17,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:18,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:19,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:20,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:21,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:22,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:23,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:24,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:25,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}},{id:"minecraft:command_block",Count:1,Slot:26,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:"/tp @e[r=2] -92.500 67.00000 242.000"}}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't seen to be able to find anything on spawning a chest with a command block that already has a command in it.
However I do have a solution for you.

1. You need to just place a command block and insert the tp command.
2. Once you have done that you can ctrl + click the middle mouse button, what that does is puts the block in your inventory but with the NBT tag which is the command in the command block.
3. Get the command block you have in your inventory and put it in a chest.
4. Once you have done that you can use the clone command to clone the chest and put it somehwere else

If it's too unclear or you don't understand I can make a video on this if you want, it'll make it easier to nderstand this.

Also there might be a better solution but I couldn't find one but there are people that are better at this then me.